# ImportError: No module named ansible after installing Ansible 2.9 via PIP

Tags: python, pip, ansible, rhel6

Would like to know if anyone encountered this same concern I've been receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/ansible2.9/bin/ansible-playbook", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ImportError: No module named ansible
```

So we have 2 ansible versions installed on our server and would like to run some jobs in ansible 2.9, we created separate environments per versions. So I activated ansible 2.9 env then proceeded to run the usual command "ansible-playbook playbook.yml .... " but we're getting this error.

The package was installed via pip, please see below:

```
[root@jenkins local]# virtualenv-2.7 --no-site-packages /usr/local/ansible2.9
New python executable in /usr/local/ansible2.9/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /usr/local/ansible2.9/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[root@jenkins local]# source /usr/local/ansible2.9/bin/activate
(ansible2.9) [root@jenkins local]# pip2.7 install git+git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git@stable-2.9
```

Please note that all required libraries have been installed. Python 2.7 is also installed. I'm using RHEL 6. Ansible 2.7 environment works fine, but this recently installed version is throwing "ImportError: No module named ansible"

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems that the permission of the Ansible 2.9 has not been set properly. Fixed it with this commands:

chmod -R 644 /usr/local/ansible2.9/
find /usr/local/ansible2.9/ -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755

Also, for Ansible 2.9 together with openstack, openstacksdk will not suffice, still need to install 'future' library.

Command: pip install ansible openstacksdk future
Source:
Issue - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/68616
Fix - https://github.com/atodorov/lorax/commit/5103e0b585564c62e3007b68d945fc56a542c474

Comment: it is worth to add we also  have to look, which user various different libraries are installed. it is advisable to use virtualenv In my case i installed openshift using root and other libs as non root user.